# What are the differences between Azure Virtual Machines & Cloud Services

Tags: azure

I'm willing to switch from AWS to Azure, however I'm a bit confused on the differences between Azure Virtual Machines & Cloud Services! what I need is a small linux server, regardless the fancy names companies like to call it (e.g. EC2), I use it to run different small uni projects written in different languages.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

An Azure Virtual Machine is basically what it sounds like -- an instance of a Windows or Linux VM that you control.  Azure basically just gives you a space to host that VM.  You control the O/S, updates, etc.

An Azure Cloud Service (a web role, a worker role, etc.) is a layer above the VM.  Azure controls the VM instance that your role runs on (O/S, updates, etc.), while you are just concerned about your application.  For a web role, that would be the code for a web application (an ASP.NET site, for instance); for a worker role, that would be the code for a service that runs in the background.

With a Cloud Service, you deploy your application to your role instances.  You really don't have control over how those instances are running (and you really don't care) -- you're just concerned that your code works.

So if you need full control over a VM, then an Azure Virtual Machine is the direction you should go.  If you're developing applications and aren't as concerned over the infrastructure (O/S updates, etc.), then the cloud services (roles) are the way to go.

I hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I find this blog post very useful for understanding the difference between various hosting options in Windows Azure: http://davidpallmann.blogspot.in/2012/07/windows-azure-is-3-lane-highway-how-to.html

Comment: I think in the context of power this bears a mention: http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/01/with-great-azure-vm-comes-great.html 
You might not always need what _you think_ is power :-)

Comment: When using Cloud Servers, do we have any control over IIS, considering a Windows Server environment? Do we choose whether they will be ran in Windows Server 2008 or 2012, for example?

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Virtual Machines** are IaaS (Infrastructure as a service). You can choose the OS to install and other software configurations.

In case of **Cloud Services**, Azure provides many different cloud services. 
An example for cloud service is **Computer Vision**. You can train the computer vision to classify and recognize images. Then you can use the REST API for computer vision (cloud service) for image classification and recognition. Here, the underlying infrastructure is out of your scope.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct?  Your definition of "cloud service" as a "Computer Vision" API puts it squarely in "SaaS", whereas I thought of cloud service as "PaaS".  I guess terminology is unfortunately loose and sloppy, and maybe I should not care so much.